# ¿ Como reutilizo espacios en una tabla hash, despreciando los mas antiguos?

Tags: c++, c, estructuras-de-datos, c++11

Tengo que procesar una gran cantidad de frases. De echo, el número de ellas es *ilimitado*: se obtienen de una fuente en Internet.

El objetivo es contar las veces que se repite una determinada frase. Como el número de ellas es, como digo, *ilimitado*, es obvio que no puedo almacenarlas todas en memoria.

Adicionalmente, se me exigen ciertas condiciones: la complejidad de cualquier operación ha de ser O(1). **No** se hace mención a las colisiones, así que de momento las estoy *despreciando* de momento.

Un ejemplo del comportamiento *esperado*:

1. Se leen 4096 frases, **todas ellas distintas**. Casualmente, **ninguna** genera colisión de *hash* con otra.
2. La tabla *hash* se *llena*. Los `4096` *huecos* están ocupados por las frases leidas.
3. Se lee una nueva frase. Su *hash* **es igual** al de una de las frases anteriores, pero la frase **es dinstinta** a todas las `4096` anteriores.
4. Elimino de la tabla **el elemento que lleva mas tiempo sin ser usado**. En este caso, sería *el primero que inserté*. **No** elimino el elemento con valor *hash* coincidente, porque es **mas moderno**.

#### EDITO

Actualmente, tengo esto:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct phrase_s {
  char text[256];
  unsigned long long count;
  struct phrase_s *prev;
  struct phrase_s *next;
} Phrase;

Phrase List[4096];

// Devuelve la hash de una cadena, limitada a 12 bits ( 0 - 4095 ).
size_t makeHash( const char * );
// Devuelve la cadena MAS ANTIGUA, aquella que hay que eliminar.
Phrase *old( void );


void addString( const char *str ) {
  size_t hash = makeHash( str );

  if( !( List[hash].count ) ) {
    // Caso fácil. No hay cadenas con hash coincidente.
    memcpy( &( List[hash].text ), str, strlen( str ) );
    List[hash].count = 1;
    List[hash].prev = NULL;
    List[hash].next = NULL;

    return;
  }

  // Caso INTERESANTE. La hash COINCIDE con otra.
  // POR HACER.
}
```

¿ Como implemento el punto *4* anterior ? ¿ Puedo continuar a partir del código que ya tengo, o son necesarias otras modificaciones ?

Reitero el tema de la complejidad. El número de operaciones a realizar ha de ser independiente del tamaño de la tabla.

<sub>**Nota:** Esta es una pregunta que se publicó hace un par días y me pareció interesante. Es *lo que pude entender con algo de sentido* de la misma, que ha sido eliminada por su autor.</sub>

#### EDITO 2

Me sigue pareciendo una pregunta interesante; seguro que hay mas buenas respuestas, que muestran la lógica a seguir en estos casos. Añado el lenguaje `C++` a las respuestas permitidas.

#### EDITO 3

Como me han indicado, hay que puntualizar el término `O( 1 )`. Normalmente, indicaría una complejidad **constante**. Puesto que estamos hablando de una tabla *hash*, añadiremos la coletilla *de media*; es decir, el algoritmo elegido ha de tener, **de media**, complejidad `O( 1 )`.

Además, para poder usar `std::unordered_map`, se admiten respuestas en C++11.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que lo que expones aquí es `O(1)`?

Comment: @NaCl Es lo que pude entender de la pregunta original. ¿ Verdad que es interesante ?

Comment: Es interesante, pero no `O(1)`, según mi entendimiento [al respecto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), con el simple hecho de decir que _"el número de ellas es ilimitado"_, ya es `O(N)` u `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @NaCl Solo hay que tener en cuenta *la tabla hash*. El resto es irrelevante. Solo se busca una tabla hash que pueda descartar las entradas basandonos en la antigüedad de las mismas.

Comment: Puesto que una función hash debe ser en la medida de lo posible lo más aleatoria posible no hay forma alguna de saber la antiguedad de los elementos dentro de la estructura adyacente juzgándolo sólo por su índice, no obstante es relativamente fácil emplear soporte a ello, la solución más simple consiste en mantener dos arreglos solapados, uno que almacene la frase y otro que almacene la fecha de agregación, así en caso de eliminar los valores viejos, basta recorrerlos.

Comment: No obstante, si se emplea la solución anterior la identificación de la frase  vieja requiere de O(n) puesto que se debe analizar todo el arreglo buscando la frase más vieja. Así que si te exigen que sea O(1) la agregación no cumple (prestad atención que exigen todas las operaciones sean constante, incluyendo en ello la agregación) , entonces, sabiendo que no siempre se requiere buscar una frase entonces la complejidad es amortiguada O(n/k), pero no O(1) ! así que lo mejor que debes hacer es ampliar la tabla hash dinamicamente

Comment: @EduenSarceño Gracias por tus comentarios. ¿ Porqué no escribes una respuesta ? No obstante, la respuesta dada por Eferion si es O(1). Despreciando las colisiones, los tiempos empleados en verificar si la frase ya existe en la tabla, y el de eliminación de la mas antigua, son independientes del tamaño de la misma. Fíjate que no usa ningún *bucle*; todos son accesos directos, sin recorrer nada.

Comment: Eso es porque optó por un chained hash table

Comment: El escenario adolece de cierta inconsistencia: si sustituimos una frase (la más antigua) por una nueva, significa que colocaremos esa frase asociada a un hash incorrecto. Por tanto, si nos volvemos a encontrar con una frase idéntica, será imposible comprobar si ya está en nuestra tabla en O(1) porque no nos podremos valer de su hash, habría que hacer una búsqueda manual.

Comment: @PabloLozano Nada de eso. Es perfectamente posible hacerlo. Seguro al 100%.

Comment: como te va con este tema???

Comment: Ya que se han cambiado las etiquetas... ¿es viable c++14? ¿y c++17?

Comment: @eferion no veo porqué no. Uso `gcc  6.3.0`, y con el compilaré las respuestas. Mientras lo soporte, no hay problema.

Comment: @Juanjo, ya veo cómo, el escenario asume que no hay colisiones, con lo que igual hash significa mismo valor. Entonces sí, una tabla hash y una lista enlazada cumplen para resolver el problema

Comment: @PabloLozano Veo que una respuesta se basa en lo que dices. ¿ Porqué no has respondido ?

Comment: Soy javero, de C o C++ ni idea más allá de la sintaxis común

Comment: @PabloLozano ¡¡ Aggg !! ¡¡ Javero !! *zape*, *zape* :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

El problema, tal y como lo has planteado, no tiene solución:

- Una tabla hash no guarda información sobre la antigüedad de cada cadena, lo que te imposibilita identificar y desechar los elementos más viejos
- Si diseñas una tabla hash y luego intentas almacenar dichos hash en una tabla en la que no cabe todo el espectro del hash... ¿De qué sirve entonces el hash?
- ¿Qué sucede si al meter el segundo elemento de la tabla colisiona su hash con el del primero? ¿Descartas una cadena cuando tienes 4095 espacios libres?

La implementación más sencilla, a mi juicio, es un buffer circular. ¿Cómo se implementa? Muy sencillo:

```
typedef struct
{
  char text[256];
} nodo;

#define NUMELEMS 4096

typedef struct
{
  nodo elementos[NUMELEMS];
  int num_elementos;
  int indice;
} buffer;
```

Bien, ya hemos definido el buffer:

- Un array que almacena 4096 elementos, siendo cada elemento capaz de almacenar una cadena de 255 caracteres.
- Un entero que indica el número de elementos en el buffer.
- Un entero que hace las veces de índice. ¿Índice de que? Esta variable nos va a permitir escribir de forma secuencial en el buffer.

Inicialización del buffer: Función sencilla... los dos enteros a 0.

```
void InitBuffer(buffer* b)
{
  b->num_elementos = 0;
  b->indice = 0;
}
```

Función para incrementar el índice: No me gusta repetir código.

```
void IncrementaIndice(int* indice)
{
  *indice= (*indice + 1) % NUMELEMS;
}
```

Insertar un elemento en el buffer: Lo que vamos a hacer ahora es reemplazar el valor apuntado por la variable `indice`... después desplazamos el índice una posición. Como el buffer es circular, si llegamos al final del mismo hay que desplazar el puntero al principio. El contador de elementos habrá que actualizarlo hasta que lleguemos al máximo de elementos... una vez alcanzado ese tope se empezarán a reemplazar los elementos más antiguos y el número de elementos permanecerá constante

```
void AddItem(buffer* b, char* str)
{
  strcpy(b->elementos[b->indice],str);

  IncrementaIndice(&b->indice);

  if( b->num_elementos < NUMELEMS )
    b->num_elementos++;
}
```

¿Cómo se usa? Facil:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct nodo
{
  char text[256];
};

#define NUMELEMS 6

struct buffer
{
  struct nodo elementos[NUMELEMS];
  int num_elementos;
  int indice;
};

void InitBuffer(struct buffer* b)
{
  b->num_elementos = 0;
  b->indice = 0;
}

void IncrementaIndice(int* indice)
{
  *indice= (*indice + 1) % NUMELEMS;
}

void AddItem(struct buffer* b, char* str)
{
  strcpy(b->elementos[b->indice].text,str);
  IncrementaIndice(&b->indice);

  if( b->num_elementos < NUMELEMS )
    b->num_elementos++;
}

int main()
{
  struct buffer miBuffer;
  InitBuffer(&miBuffer);

  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
    char cad[256];
    scanf("%s",cad);
    AddItem(&miBuffer,cad);
  }

  printf("Numero de elementos: %d\n",miBuffer.num_elementos);
  printf("Cadenas almacenadas:\n");

  int indice = miBuffer.indice;
  for( int i=0; i<miBuffer.num_elementos; i++ )
  {
    printf(" - %s\n",miBuffer.elementos[indice].text);
    IncrementaIndice(&indice);
  }
}
```

Como ves, insertar un elemento tiene una complejidad O(1) ya que no requiere bucles de ningun tipo... y da igual el número de elementos que haya almacenados. Además siempre sobreescribirá los valores más antiguos y su gestión es de lo más simple.

---

Edición motivada por el siempre atento @Trauma... no tuve en cuenta que no admitían duplicados... la solución entonces pasa por integrar, como comentas en la pregunta, un sistema de hash al sistema de buffer circular:

Un posible hash para las cadenas pudiera ser ([fuente](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)), Lo he adaptado chapuceramente a `unsigned short`... las colisiones serán más posibles pero reducimos el campo a cubrir:

```
unsigned short get_hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned short hash = 5381;
    short c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

Vale, ahora que podemos generar un hash toca plantear cómo conjugar los dos mundos... a mi se me ocurre tener dos vectores: el circular que ya hemos visto y uno de hashes. De esta forma saber si un hash está ya ocupado es tan sencillo como mirar la tabla de hashes. ¿Cómo se relacionan ambas listas? Yo creo que es mejor tirar por lo simple... la tabla de hashes tiene un elemento por posible hash (de ahí que haya hecho la tabla de tipo `unsigned short`). Inicialmente todos los valores valen 0. Cuando se va a insertar un elemento se comprueba si la posición dada por el hash de la cadena está a 0 o a 1... si está a 1 ya existe una cadena y no se inserta en el buffer mientras que si vale 0 tenemos vía libre.

Para gestionar correctamente la tabla de hash hay que cargar la librería `limits.h`. Así el tamaño de la tabla de hashes será el correcto independientemente del sistema en el que se compile el programa:

```
#include <limits.h>

struct buffer
{
  struct nodo elementos[NUMELEMS];
  char hashes[USHRT_MAX];
  int num_elementos;
  int indice;
};
```

Ahora hay que actualizar la inicialización... pasando un poco de rendimiento (la mejora sería despreciable), ya tiene sentido usar `memset`:

```
void InitBuffer(struct buffer* b)
{
  memset(b,0,sizeof(struct buffer));
}
```

Ya tenemos todos los bytes del buffer a 0 (incluyendo la tabla hash)... Vamos a modificar la función para añadir elementos:

```
void AddItem(struct buffer* b, char* str)
{
  unsigned short strHash = get_hash(str);
  if( b->hashes[strHash] == 0 )
  {
    b->hashes[strHash] = 1;

    char* posicion = b->elementos[b->indice].text;
    if( *posicion != 0 )
      b->hashes[get_hash(posicion)] = 0;

    strcpy(posicion,str);

    IncrementaIndice(&b->indice);

    if( b->num_elementos < NUMELEMS )
    b->num_elementos++;
  }
}
```

La lógica es sencilla:

- Se comprueba que el hash de la nueva cadena es 0 y, de se así se continua y se pone ese hash a 1.
- Si se va a sobreescribir una cadena se borra antes su hash (recordemos que no hay duplicados)
- Se copia la nueva cadena
- Se incrementa el indice y el contador

Y para rematar nos falta una función que se me había pasado antes. Necesitamos una función que nos de el indice inicial del buffer, que será:

- 0 mientras no se haya llenado del todo
- El indice actual en caso contrario. Es el siguiente indice en ser borrado luego es facil deducir que ese es el elemento más antiguo.

Dicho con código:

```
int inicio(struct buffer* b)
{
  if( b->num_elementos == NUMELEMS )
    return b->indice;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Y ya solo falta corregir el bucle de presentación del `main` para usar este indice como inicial en vez de lo que había antes:

```
for( int i=0, indice = Inicio(&miBuffer); i<miBuffer.num_elementos; i++ )
{
  printf(" - %s\n",miBuffer.elementos[indice].text);
  IncrementaIndice(&indice);
}
```

---

**Versión C++11**

En este caso he intentado forzar la máquina para que no sea una simple traducción del código en C:

- La lista de elementos se compone a partir de una lista doblemente enlazada. Así sacar un elemento de la lista (caso de duplicados) no requiere operaciones costosas
- Para saber si un elemento se encuentra en la lista se recurre a un `std::unordered_map`. Este mapa almacena los valores que se encuentran en la lista y un puntero al nodo que contiene el valor.
- La lista se crea a partir de `std::unique_ptr`. Usar punteros crudos era demasiado fácil y la idea era plantear algo totalmente diferente... y sí, con `std::unique_ptr` se puede crear una lista doblemente enlazada.
- La lista se basa en plantillas, para poder personalizarla al gusto.

Y bueno, aquí os dejo el resultado de estar tecleando un rato. El código puede ser complejo de seguir si no tienes un buen nivel de C++.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace UniquePtrUtils
{
  // alias de puntero a funcion
  template<class T>
  using Functor = std::function<void(T*)>;

  // Alias del unique_ptr, para evitar repetir codigo
  template<class T>
  using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T,Functor<T>>;

  // Funcion dummy. Se usa en algunos unique_ptr
  template<class T>
  void NoDelete(T*)
  { /* no hace nada */ }

  // Obtiene un unique_ptr que apunta al mismo objeto que otro unique_ptr
  // El unique_ptr devuelto no borra el objeto apuntado
  template<class T>
  UniquePtr<T> RefUnique(UniquePtr<T> & original)
  {
    return UniquePtr<T>(original.get(),NoDelete<T>);
  }

  // Utilidad para crear un unique_ptr escribiendo poco
  template<class T>
  UniquePtr<T> NewUnique(T * ptr)
  {
    return UniquePtr<T>(ptr,std::default_delete<T>());
  }
}

// Representa un nodo de la lista
template<class T>
struct Node
{
    // Alias... para no repetir
    using NodePtr = UniquePtrUtils::UniquePtr<Node<T>>;

    T value;          // valor almacenado por el nodo
    NodePtr next;     // puntero al siguiente nodo
    NodePtr previous; // puntero al nodo anterior

    // Constructor del nodo
    Node(T && value)
      : value{std::forward<T>(value)}
    { }

    // Destructor. Quitad el comentario si quereis ver cuando se borran
    // realmente los nodos
    ~Node()
    { /* std::cout << "Delete Node" << std::endl; */ }
};

// Clase que gestiona la lista de elementos
template<class T, int SIZE>
class RingBuffer
{
public:

  using RingNode = Node<T>;
  using RingNodePtr = typename RingNode::NodePtr;

  RingBuffer()
    : m_bufferSize{0}
  { }

  // Añade un nuevo elemento a la lista
  void Add(T && value)
  {
    // Si el elemento ya existe y la lista tiene mas de un elemento
    // (en listas de un elemento no hay que hacer nada)
    // sacamos el nodo antiguo de la lista.
    auto it = m_hash.find(std::forward<T>(value));
    if( it != m_hash.end() )
    {
      if( m_bufferSize == 1 )
        return;

      // Obtenemos una referencia de los nodos anterior y siguiente
      auto prevPtr = Ref(it->second->previous);
      auto nextPtr = Ref(it->second->next);

      // esta operacion permite que el nodo a eliminar se borre el solito
      // cuando el codigo abandone el if
      auto tempPtr = std::move(prevPtr->next);

      // Remapeamos los enlaces del nodo anterior
      nextPtr->previous = Ref(it->second->previous);

      // Si el nodo a sacar es el nodo primario de la lista
      // tenemos que actualizar este nodo primario para evitar
      // que la lista se borre por error
      if( m_first.get() == tempPtr.get() )
      {
        m_first.release();
        m_first = std::move(it->second->next);
        it->second->next = Ref(m_first);

        // Mapeamos una referencia... el ultimo nodo y enlaza con el primero
        // con un puntero que no borre. No queremos tener un borrado doble  
        prevPtr->next = Ref(it->second->next);
      }
      else
      {
        // en caso contrario basta con remapear el nodo siguiente
        prevPtr->next = std::move(it->second->next);
      }

      // sacamos el nodo viejo de la lista
      m_hash.erase(it);

      // y claro, la lista ahora tiene un nodo menos  
      m_bufferSize--;
    }

    // Si la lista esta llena hay que sobreescribir un nodo
    if( m_bufferSize == SIZE )
    {
      m_current = Next(m_current);    // avanzamos el cursor
      m_hash.erase(m_current->value); // quitamos el valor a borrar de la tabla de hash
      m_current->value = std::forward<T>(value); // asignamos el nuevo valor
    }
    else
    {
      // Si la lista no esta llena añadimos un nuevo nodo
      RingNodePtr node = UniquePtrUtils::NewUnique(new RingNode(std::forward<T>(value)));
      m_bufferSize++;
      if( !m_first ) // Si es el primer nodo de la lista...
      {
        m_first = std::move(node);
        m_first->next = Ref(m_first);
        m_first->previous = Ref(m_first);
        m_current = Ref(m_first);
      }
      else
      {
        // La lista tiene al menos un nodo...
        m_current->next = std::move(node);
        m_current->next->previous = Ref(m_current);
        m_current->next->next = Ref(m_first);
        m_first->previous = Next(m_current);

        m_current = Next(m_current);
      }

      // El nuevo valor se añade al mapa de hash
      m_hash.insert(std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(value),Ref(m_current)));
    }
  }

  // Funcion para imprimir la lista
  // Pense en implementar iteradores... pero se me ha hecho tarde
  // Puede ser un ejercicio interesante implementar los iteradores
  void Print()
  {
    if( !m_first )
    {
      std::cout << "Empty list\n";
      return;
    }

    RingNodePtr node = Ref(m_current);
    do
    {
        std::cout << node->value << ' ';
        node = Prev(node);
    } while( node->value != m_current->value );
    std::cout <<'\n';
  }

private:

  size_t m_bufferSize;
  RingNodePtr m_first;
  RingNodePtr m_current;
  std::unordered_map<T,RingNodePtr> m_hash;

  // Utilidad para avanzar al siguiente nodo    
  RingNodePtr Next(RingNodePtr& node)
  {
    return Ref(node->next);
  }

  // Utilidad para retroceder al nodo anterior
  RingNodePtr Prev(RingNodePtr& node)
  {
    return Ref(node->previous);
  }

  // Obtiene un unique_ptr que no borra  
  RingNodePtr Ref(RingNodePtr& node)
  {
    return UniquePtrUtils::RefUnique<RingNode>(node);
  }
};
```

Para ver el ejemplo funcionando: [enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VbSUIUgHjTs6lXPs)

Hay formas más sencillas de hacer esto pero mi intención no sera hacerlo por la vía sencilla. Espero que otras respuestas exploren nuevas opciones.

Comment: Cerca. **MUY** cerca. Pero te has saltado un detalle: las frases **se pueden repetir**, en cuyo caso no se puede guardar por duplicado.

Comment: @Trauma... si eso ya lo arreglo mañana que estoy muerto :)

Comment: @Trauma na... me has picado y ahora ya si me voy a dormir XD

Comment: jejeje ... tampoco hacía falta, no voy a soltar la *pasta* tan pronto ;-) Esperaré un par de días, a ver que pasa. Una *cosilla*. Algo hay por ahí, que empieza llenando `buffer.elementos[]` por el índice `1` en lugar de `0` ;-)

Comment: @Trauma sabes que no respondo por la pasta... simplemente son respuestas que se me pasan y por eso no participo

Comment: Era por hacer un chiste, no lo tomes en serio ;-)

Comment: @Trauma y lo que dices del 1... no lo veo, el único 1 que existe es el de la tabla hash

Comment: @Trauma no me enfado... la comunicación escrita que es muy fría

Comment: `*indice= (*indice + 1) % NUMELEMS;`. Como inicializas `buffer.indice = 0`, lo anterior se transforma en `*indice = ( 0 + 1 ) % NUMELEMS`, que es `*indice = 1`. Se salta el índice `0` al empezar. No es nada serio, un simple detalle menor.

Comment: @Trauma pero eso es **despues** de escribir el dato en el buffer...

Comment: ¡¡ Ahhhggg !! Cierto. Muy cierto. Estuve probando el código anoche y en una de las pruebas, comenté dentro de `main( )` ... y no caí en eso. ¡ Con razón me imprimía los índices empezando por 1 ! Va a ser verdad lo de que hay que dormir xD ( o, alternativamente, tomar mas café xD )

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60952/discussion-between-eferion-and-trauma).

Comment: @PabloLozano el ejemplo está con enteros porque es mas facil ver un ejemplo... pero como puedes observar es una plantilla... puede trabajar con cadenas sin problemas. En cualquier caso no te preocupes que cuando llegue a casa pongo un ejemplo con cadenas

Comment: @eferion Lo de `El código puede ser complejo de seguir si no tienes un buen nivel de C++.` es **literalmente cierto**. No tengo ni idea de lo que hace tu código :-O Estoy mirándolo, pero no pillo *ni papa* ^_^

Comment: @Juanjo jajajajaja. Si tengo tiempo este fin de semana publico una versión idéntica gestionando la memoria a pelo. Lo que hace el código es *trampear* ciertos `unique_ptr` para que no borren el objeto al que apuntan. Así evito errores por intentar borrar dos veces el mismo elemento. Solo los punteros `siguiente` de los nodos que cuelgan de `m_first` son capaces de borrar elementos al desreferenciarse... quitando eso lo demás es lógica de punteros para gestionar una lista doblemente enlazada

Comment: @Juanjo lo hice así para que la lista fuese homogénea (todos los punteros iguales) pero sin perder la gestión automática de la memoria

Comment: @eferion No es necesario que añadas mas, ya te lo has *currao* bastante. Ya le voy cogiendo el *tranquillo* a tu código. Me me falta nivel, que le vamos a hacer :-)

Comment: @Juanjo por cierto, ¿al final esta respuesta resuelve tu problema? Si es así te agradecería que la marcases como solución para que sirva como referencia futura

Comment: @eferion Perdona mi *despiste*, con el tema de la recompensa, sinceramente, se me pasó el aceptarla :-)